# videoview video disappear after orientation change

Tags: android, layout, orientation, android-videoview

I am new with android and i am making a simple application where i will get a video from local device and play it in a videoview in my layout. Playing the video works fine but when i change orientation from portrait to landscape, the video disappear. I believe i need to save the state of the activity. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private int position = 0;
private VideoView vidView;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO = 1;
String vidDecodableString;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonLoadVideo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadVideo);
    this.vidView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myVideo);

    buttonLoadVideo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data){
            Uri selectedVideo = data.getData();

            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedVideo, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            vidDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            //URI
            Uri vidUri = Uri.parse(vidDecodableString);
            vidView.setVideoURI(vidUri);

            MediaController vidControl = new MediaController(this);
            vidControl.setAnchorView(vidView);
            vidView.setMediaController(vidControl);
            vidView.start();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please select video to play.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("Position", vidView.getCurrentPosition());
    vidView.pause();
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    position = savedInstanceState.getInt("Position");
    vidView.seekTo(position);
}
```

}

After i run the code, the selecting and playing of the video works but when i change the orientation, the video loaded disappear. Where am i doing wrong. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this attribute in manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".YourActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```

Comment: it worked.! i forgot about this. hahaha. so silly of me. i still need to remember so many things. hahaha. thanks for the help.